# Where is Puppet's enviroments directory on Amazon Linux2?

Tags: amazon-ec2, linux, puppet

I am using Puppet version 3.8.7 on Amazon Linux2, trying to find the directory containing the Puppet environments.

I tried to find it with the `find` command looking for files named "production" or defaults, following the names used in a tutorial using ubuntu, but there is no production or default file or directory on the Amazon Linux as there is on ubuntu version.

The distribution of Puppet I downloaded was

http://yum.puppetlabs.com/puppetlabs-release-el-7.noarch.rpm

Answer (score 1):

You tried look on `/opt` or `/etc` probably the puppetlabs folder must be in one of these directories.
Amazon Linux it's based on CentOS/RedHat family.